# Weight Painting/Deform in shoulders

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, weight-painting, topology

So I have been messing around a lot with the **weight painting** on the shoulders.

I'm still new so I don't know much about the type of weights should be on the shoulders, I've tried a lot of different weights but my model keeps deforming.

I'm content with **sliding** the arm **forward/backwards** like when you're **walking**, but moving it in another way like raising your hand for a high five or moving your arm back to throw a punch, the shoulder deforms and I don't know why.

Is this because of my weighting, or because of the model itself?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is because 2 things: 1st it the position of the joint itself (see point 2): http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34858/7777, second is twisting in the shoulder - see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41550/7777. There is no twisting in the shoulder, only in the upper arm.

Comment: probable your bone has a wrong rotation center. If you could just move that rotation center in edit mode it should at least improve your rig

Answer (score 1):

I'm very inexperienced when it comes to rigging, but I'll try to point you in the right direction, your rig lacks the collarbones, as scuh you expect their behaviour to be included in the shoulder.

[image]
this guys right here.

I think doing your own rig can be agreat learning experience and you can also tailor it to your own needs, I'd suggest importing the rigify rig and studying it a bit to see how it works, also looking at a few anatomical references to understand where you should insert the bones into your model.

Also skinning is very trial and error, try animating different movements and seeing how your model reacts, most high end rigs have corrective blendshapes which iron out some kinks when doing certain movements, or bulge out muscle when flexing, many ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with rigging characters, but no one else has posted an answer, so here's what I know:

Check the weights for the surrounding bones. The deformation looks like the upper arm bone strength is mush higher than the shoulder/torso bone strength. Blending the values between the two should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Thread! The answer on this one helped me out a ton!!
[Shoulder deformations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/shoulder-deformations)

You divide your upper arm-bone into two, make them behave like one bone, but the upper bone of those two doesnt copy the rotation of the bottom one :) hope that helps!