# My human mesh twists strangely while moving armature

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

Please help, I want my character to move like a normal human would but when I move his arms or legs it twists kind of weirdly. If someone could just simply tell me what I need to do, it would be much appreciated. [image][image]

Comment: I think that you could add more details to your armature. Just add more bones and try to turn them into a shape and position that correspond to the human body. It would works better I think.

Answer (score 0):

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34858

hope this helps im pretty sure its a issue with the bones axis rotation i was have a similar issue  all in all this video helped me more then anything

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYiAd_08-0k&t=77s

Comment: Link based answers aren't very popular here, use comment section for this.

Answer (score 0):

- You may need to check the weight on the mesh: adjust for smoother transitions.
- Maybe your model lacks detail, but don't overdo it!)
- Make sure your bone is not rotated or too high (deep in the body).